# How to make sure only single instance of timer running in a class?

Tags: ios, swift

I am starting timer inside `ParentView` class. On some button click I stop timer and if needed start that again. This works fine. However, if perform those button clicks quickly I see there will be couple of timer instances which keeps firing target `scheduledTask` method.

class MyTimer {

```
weak var delegate: ParentViewDelegate?

private var timer: Timer?

func start() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(scheduledTask), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer?.fire()
}

@objc private func scheduledTask() {
   print("timer call this per seconds")
}

func stop() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}
```

```
final class VideoPlayerContainer: UIView {

    // MARK: - Properties
    private var mytimer: Mytimer? = Mytimer()
}
```

How should I make sure there will be always only once instance of timer and stop actions kills that timer present in parentView?

Comment: What does the button click function look like?

Comment: add `if timer != nil { stop() }` first in your `start` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply check if there is already a timer before you start a new one;

```
func start() {
    guard timer == nil else {
        return
    }
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(scheduledTask), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer?.fire()
}
```

Alternatively, invalidate any existing timer before you start the new one;

```
func start() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(scheduledTask), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer?.fire()
}
```

Comment: Alternative approach may work for my problem. However ```if timer != nil { stop() }``` works perfect in my scneario.